# Can you add videos automatically to "Watch Later" based on a subscription?

Tags: youtube, automation, youtube-watch-later

Is there a way to automatically add videos to your "Watch Later" list if you are subscribed to a channel?

I want to utilize my "Watch Later" list to play through my subscriptions so that I can leave the window running in the background during my workday without constantly going back to the YouTube tab in my browser to add videos to the list.

I've looked at `ifttt.com` and haven't been able to find a task within the **YouTube** channel that will allow me to interact with my subscriptions.

Comment: I know it's been a long time ago, but I've implemented the software that does this by pressing one button. Here are the sources and you can request the executable file if you need one. github.com/JustMeGaaRa/Silent.YouTube.MusicFeed

Answer (score 2):

I've set it up to work almost like that. 
Since Google shut down the YouTube subscription RSS feed it's a bit more work.
What I do is first grab the RSS feed for a channel I want to subscribe to.

The URL for a YouTube channel RSS feed is:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/USER_NAME/uploads
```

Then I create a new IFTTT recipe and add a feed with the URL of that RSS feed.
And finally, I add new items in that RSS feed to my Pocket.

So I end up watching everything through Pocket which is not too bad since they have apps for web, desktop, and my iPhone and I can mark stuff as read there.

I recently checked and IFTTT doesn't currently have a way to automatically add to YouTube Watch Later, but if they add it at some point then that would let me watch directly in YouTube (although I must say that YouTube's Watch Later management sucks big time, especially on the iPhone).

Answer (score 1):

I made a Google Apps Script that will do this exact thing. If interested you can check it out here: [Automatically add new YouTube videos to Watch Later list](https://chirav.substack.com/p/videos-auto-to-watch-later?utm_campaign=rebecca&utm_medium=web&utm_source=stackexchange).

Basically, the script will go through the list of YouTube channels you give and whenever a new video gets uploaded by any of the channels it will add it to your desired playlist. You can change the frequency of the check as per your liking by changing it in triggers in Apps Script.

Answer (score -3):

Grew tired of this too. Currently browsing the web for such requests and wanted to share this userscript.
https://github.com/ackoujens/youtube-subcriptions-watch-later